# Joomla 3.3 deprecated function for JRequest::getVar()

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, jrequest

```
public function storeans()
{
    $user   = JFactory::getUser();
    $post   = JRequest::getVar('post');
}
```

In the above code, `JRequest` is deprecated.

What is the equivalent that can be used in Joomla 3.x?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`JRequest` has been deprecated in the earlier release of Joomla 3.x

Use `JFactory::getApplication()->input` instead.

For getting any variable (say name) from post method, use below line of code.

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('name');
```

Comment: JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('name'); use this i can't get the values. If any solution is there

Comment: If you want to collect all the data posted then use JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getArray(array())l as @Lodder has suggested.
If it is not working then please share your code.

Comment: JRequest was deprecated in Joomla 2.5 actually and JInput was also introduced then. However note that JInput was not compatible with having magic quotes enabled so it wasn't used by core in 2.5. However if you're extension needs 2.5/3.x compatibility it is available

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, I'll just say that you need to use `JInput`. More information on this can be read about here:

https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

So to start off with: you need to call `JInput` via the application like so:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

Then, if you wish to get a single value, you can use:

```
$name = $jinput->get('name');
```

Or if you wish to get an array of data, let's say from a form with multiple fields, then you can use:

```
$data = $jinput->post->getArray(array());
```