# Filtering Data in Php oop

Tags: php, sql

After I click the search button - there's no data output in the web page. What should I do?
This is my view page

````
        <label>DATE FROM:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Start"  name="date1" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['date1']) ? $_POST['date1'] : '' ?>" />
        <label>DATE TO: </label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="End"  name="date2" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['date2']) ? $_POST['date2'] : '' ?>"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success validate"><?php echo JText::_('SEARCH'); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_ajtechsadmin" />
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="submissioncsf.FilterDate()" />

        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>```

---and this is my functions---

```    public function getFilterDate(){
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $date_start = JRequest::getVar('date1');
        $date_end = JRequest::getVar('date2');
        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            
        $query -> select('feedback,date_submitted')
               -> from('#__pm_submission_csf')
               -> where('date_submitted');
               $db->setQuery((string) $query);
            //    $feedback = $data['feedback'];
               $date_submitted = ['date_submitted'];

         $date_start = date("yyyy-mm-dd", strtotime($_POST['date1']));
         $date_end = date("yyyy-mm-dd", strtotime($_POST['date2']));

        if($_GET['SEARCH']){

            if($date_start ){
                $sql .= "";
                $sql .= "WHERE date_submitted > " . $date_start;
                $sql .= (!empty($date_submitted) ? (empty($sql) ? ' date_submitted = ' . $db->Quote($date_start) : ', date_submitted = ' . $db->Quote($date_end)) : '');
             }
            if($date_end){
                $sql .= " AND date_submitted " . $date_end;
                $sql .= (!empty($date_submitted) ? (empty($sql) ? ' date_submitted = ' . $db->Quote($date_start) : ', date_submitted = ' . $db->Quote($date_end)) : '');
            }

             $row=mysqli_num_rows($query);
             if($row>0){
                while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $fetch['feedback']?></td>
       <td><?php echo $fetch['submission_id']?></td>
       <td><?php echo $fetch['user_id']?></td>
       <td><?php echo $fetch['date_submitted']?></td>
   </tr>

<?php
       }}}}}

?> ```
````

Comment: This looks like bits of code that have been cut and pasted from different places and then changed at random.  Perhaps you could start by describing what you're attempting to do and then working through your issues step by step.

Comment: I've used some references from online. the view and functions do have a separate php file. my goal is to filter the data between two dates.

Comment: I'm happy that you've posted your question here.  As I've said twice on Stack Overflow, there is no point where you declare `$sql = ''`; then after you are finished concatenating, you never do anything with `$sql`.  We should not see `mysqli_()` functions called within a Joomla application.  Please also see: [Joomla 3.3 deprecated function for JRequest::getVar()](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/8883/12352) I find it odd that you are checking `$_GET` then accessing `$_POST` with `isset($_GET['date1']) ? $_POST['date1']`

Comment: If a `<label>` tag is not wrapped around its child element, then it should have a `for` attribute that points to the input field's `id`.  Did you test what `date("yyyy-mm-dd", ...)` does?  You probably want: `date("Y-m-d", ...)`.  `WHERE` clause rules are not separated by commas -- you are going to want `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you for helping me, thanks a lot. Issues found are fixed.  However,  I've tried to call the variable **$start_date** but the output doesnt match from the start date I choose.

Comment: The current version of your question is a little too messy for volunteers to tackle.  I recommend that you completely overwrite your question with the best version of your currently broken code.  Hopefully your new version will be more narrow in its faults and will be more attractive for the community to answer. You will be able to [edit] your question as many times as you like until it is made clear and attractive.

Comment: this is **noted**, thank you again mick